# Validating xml against schema with lxml does not catch ID/IDREF problems

Tags: python, xml, validation, xsd, lxml

I've been validating xml files against their associated schemas with lxml but I found out that it does not (or appears not to) catch the situation where you have an IDREF type without the matching ID type in the document.
For example:
Attribute "internalRefId" is of type "IDREF" and attribute "id" is of type "ID".
In the schema:

```
<xs:attribute name="internalRefId" type="xs:IDREF"/>
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
```

When used in xml file:

```
....See <internalRef internalRefId="T0003" internalRefTargetType="irtt02"/>....
```

There should be a corresponding element tag with attribute ID="T0003" such as

```
<table id="T0003">
```

This is a problem if the there is no id="T0003" anywhere in the xml document and from my understanding that is the purpose of specifying attributes as IDREF/ID types.
And therefore should be caught by an xml validator.
But I can't figure out how to get lxml validator to do this.  If I remove, for example, the above table element, lxml validation does not catch this and considers it still valid.
My validation code is similar to the following:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

tree = ET.parse(filePath)
schema = ET.XMLSchema(ET.parse(somePathtoSchemaXsdFile))

isValid = schema.validate(tree)
```

1. If lxml does verify IDREF/ID matches, then what do I need to do?
2. If lxml does not handle this, the reason why would be nice to know, but more importantly what options do I have?  The environment is primarily python based and free is preferred but other solutions are on the table.

Comment: Similar unanswered question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23368515/407651

Comment: @mzjn Thanks.  I did see that question but it was from 2014 and no answer was provided.